# Apache mod_rewrite for specific folders and paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have found dozens of articles online on how to setup mod_rewrites but for the love of God I can't figure out how to PROPERLY force HTTPS on ALL pages and after that force HTTP on certain directories or (already rewritten) pages.

Now this one gets really tricky as I need HTTPS on this directory, except for two cases, such as "/surf" which actually is rewritten from "surf.php", and "promote-([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$" which is rewritten from "promote.php?user=$1" :

```
<Directory /home/rotate/public_html/ptp/>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
ErrorDocument 404 "<h1>Oops! Couldn't find that page.</h1>"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^promote-([0-9]+)$ promote.php?user=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

</Directory>
```

I have tried some stuff but which only resulted in some weird redirection loops...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(surf|promote-([0-9]+)$) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

So basically I need to force HTTPS everywhere in /ptp/ except /ptp/surf (which is rewritten from surf.php AND /ptp/promote-123 which is rewritten from promote.php?user=123

Currently I'm using PHP to redirect to HTTP or HTTPS as per my needs but I know that it would be much faster if I could manage to do it via rewrites.
Any pointers, tips, suggestions? Thanks.

UPDATE2: This worked:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^(surf|promote(-[0-9]+)?) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteRule ^promote-([0-9]+)$ promote.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
```

However, the resources such as javascript, fonts etc, were being blocked by the browser, unless I specified absolute HTTPS paths. Note that this never happened when redirecting through PHP...

Comment: check the answer and let me know if it is not working for you

Comment: did you made it?

Comment: I suggest you to make the second part as a new question. Since all the points in your question is for a working rule and it is fixed with my answer. People didn't notice the second part which you added as an update. Try to make it as another question if you didn't get a solution. It is not a problem with rewrite rules. It is mixed content issue which happens when you load HTTP content over HTTPS and vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a little bit and it works perfectly

## Changes

Remove the Change the `RewriteRule` to match file to `.php` to bottom.

Remove the `$` sign that is End of the pattern

As Said in the update `promote-1111` will redirect to `promote.php?user=$1` change the `promote-[0-9]+` to `promote(-[0-9]+)?` otherwise it will override in the second redirection as you redirecting it to `promote.php?user=$1`

## The Code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^(surf|promote(-[0-9]+)?) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

#### The page surf

[image]

#### The Page Index

Never mind the error message shown in this image. Since I tried it from my localhost, it won't have a certificate.

Will work with servers

[image]

Comment: That didn't work. Same redirect errors on HTTPS: example.com/ptp/surf redirecting to example.com/surf. Note that the exisint 2 rules must be left in place. I just need to force HTTPS in folder /ptp/ except for /ptp/surf and /ptp/promote-23232 (any number) but note that these are already rewritten paths!

Comment: @Ivan If you copied the exact above, then try to clear the cache and try again. Still didn't work, let me know

Comment: Nope, same redirect loop everywhere. Check the updated post. Almost there just need to figure our the 2nd case, which is the variable promote-(numbers).

Comment: I didn't give extra brace to numbers `promote-[0-9]+`. please try this

Comment: Tried your code for the 3rd time, removed all my own, same thing. Redirect loop on every page.

Comment: loop means is it going infinitely?

Comment: Yes, browser giving redirect loop error. Trying with 3 browsers, every time clearing the cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146937/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-ivan).

Comment: @Ivan please click the chat link

Comment: No, haven't solved it. It's definitely related to rewrite rules though...

Comment: Is js and CSS loading differently in surf and promo

Comment: Regular css and js (on page load) is loading just fine. However, there is content generated such as a div, fonts and additional js being loaded through javascript after the page loads. This content is from the same domain. So I'm assuming this content is not being rewritten somehow.

Comment: is it didn't work for only one page or for both surf and promo?

Comment: Only for surf, as this is the only page where I have content being generated through javascript after page load. Every other page was working fine.

Comment: that is because of "Mixed Content" issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Comment: resource from https will be blocked at http and vice versa.

Comment: Why doesn't that happen if I redirect through PHP? I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: PHP redirect and htaccess redirect are different. in htaccess redirect, the entire files will be served via HTTP(S). excluding the 2 we set.

Answer (score 1):

Your rules aren't in the "update" working because of side effects of using `<Directory>` context.  Each substitution starts processing again.

When you request /promote-123 and rewrite it to put the numbers in the query string, you can't then match the numbers as if they're still in the path.  You'll need to match the rewriten path and the numbers with RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (if you care about the numbers)

Comment: Just looking at RewriteLog (2.2)/ LogLevel rewrite:trace8 (2.4) for a few minutes would make these kinds of interaction much more clear.

Comment: The rules were working, however I hit another issue: by rewriting from HTTPS to HTTP, the html resources such as javascript, fonts etc. were being blocked by the browser, unless I specifed absolute HTTPS paths for them. Note that this never happened when using redirect from PHP. Perhaps you know a workaround for this matter?